# Shortcut to kill an application

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, shortcuts, kill, labview

Labview (a programming language) has this nasty habit of hanging after an error while executing and our programmer always goes to task manager to manually kill it. Now I think as a Super User he should use something "easier" to do this!

So now I want to create a (keyboard) shortcut to kill Labview, any thoughts on the best way to do this?

Note: This is for Windows XP

Comment: We can only assume that you are using windows?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This might help](http://lifehacker.com/5232692/kill-frozen-windows-apps-easily).

[image]

> To create your own quick-killing
>   mechanism, just create a new shortcut
>   anywhere, using this as the location:
>
> ```
> taskkill.exe /f /im labview.exe
> ```
>
> Once you are done, you can change the
>   icon, or even assign a shortcut key in
>   the properties dialog—just make sure
>   the shortcut is on your desktop or in
>   the start menu if you want the hotkey
>   to work, since Windows hotkeys don't
>   work in the Quick Launch.

Kudos to Lifehacker and HowToGeek

Comment: This is nearly what I need, though how do I have to change it to only kill Labview?

Comment: taskkill.exe /f /im labview.exe

Comment: Tie this shortcut together with SlickRun and you'll have fast, mouseless access to it as well. ("a free floating command line utility for Windows.")
http://www.bayden.com/Slickrun/

Answer (score 3):

You can use [pskill](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896683.aspx?ppud=4) (in a batch file) to do this.

File KillDodgyApp.bat will be on your desktop and contain the text line:

```
pskill -t labview.exe
```

and this can be double clicked to close the dodgy application.

(Alternatively, create a shortcut to pskill.exe with the parameters "-t labview.exe")

Comment: pskill is treated as virus by many anti-viruses. False positive, of course.

Comment: Auch... Awh well I mainly upvoted sean's answer for providing a useful comment on the other answer

Comment: Hi guys, I'd just like to remind users of legacy systems like windows XP Home and below that `pskill.exe` must be [downloaded](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896683.aspx) first. Copy and Paste the Pskill.exe file into `C:\WINDOWS\system32`.