# How can I kill a process from the command prompt on Windows NT?

Tags: windows, command-line, process, kill

How can I kill a process from the command prompt on Windows NT? Preferably with a tool that comes with the operating system.

Comment: +1 Actually a much better question than how I formatted it yesterday for XP: http://superuser.com/questions/48864/shortcut-to-kill-an-application Though I don't think there will be much of a difference

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you had XP or later you could use `TASKKILL`.  This on not NT though.

I think you're going to have to download something to do this.  I'd recommend [`pskill` from Sysinternals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896683.aspx).

You can use this either with a process ID or just with a process name.  For example:

```
pskill notepad.exe
```

Another option is [`KILL` from the NT Resource Kit](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/197155).

Comment: "This on not NT though." -- Windows XP is NT series, and has `taskkill`. So I guess you meant "NT 4.0 or older", or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

To kill process with children (like apache), from Windows XP to Windows Seven :

```
TASKKILL /T /F /PID 4520
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use VBScript and WMI to kill processes:

```
Dim strComputer,objWMIService,objProcessList,objProcess
strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
Set objProcessList = objWMIService.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Process WHERE Name = 'THE PROCESS NAME'")
For Each objProcess in objProcessList
  objProcess.Terminate()
Next
```

Or in modern windows editions, we can use Powershell:

```
Stop-Process -Name "PROCESS NAME WITHOUT EXTENSION"
```

Answer (score -2):

There are a couple of choices:

**KILL Command**

> `kill process name or id`

or

> `kill -f process name or id`

**AT Utility**

> `at time /interactive cmd /c kill -f process name or id`

**And of course**

> Reboot :-)

Comment: The AT utility doesn't kill the command.  The command line is still using KILL.  The advantage of calling it using AT as the KILL runs as LocalSystem instead of the current user which means it my kill some more processes which are less inclined to die.