# How to create a shortcut to end a specific task?

Tags: windows, windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey, hotkeys

I am trying to achieve the following: when I press a combination of keys, let's say Ctrl+f4, I would like to end the application called "Matlab". I have downloaded AutoKey and tried the following but to no avail...

```
#IfWinActive EditPlus - 
^w::Send ^{F4}
```

Comment: Hope these 2 similar threads can help you: [How to create a shortcut or batch file to kill a process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51257395/how-to-create-a-shortcut-or-batch-file-to-kill-a-process), [Shortcut to kill an application](https://superuser.com/questions/48864/shortcut-to-kill-an-application)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From AHK help:

> WinClose
>
> Closes the specified window.
>
> WinClose , WinTitle, WinText, SecondsToWait, ExcludeTitle, ExcludeText

Example

```
if WinExist("Untitled - Notepad")
    WinClose ; use the window found above
else
    WinClose, Calculator
```

If you are just trying to bind shortcut to sequence, then Ctrl+F4 would look like

```
^{F4}::
Send, My First Script
return
```

Here's an explanation of the above code:

The first line: ^{F4}:: is the hotkey. ^ means Ctrl, {F4} is F4. Anything to the left of :: are the keys you need to press.

The second line: Send, My First Script is how you send keystrokes. Send is the command, anything after the comma (,) will be typed.

The third line: return. This will become your best friend. It literally stops code from going any further, to the lines below. This will prevent many issues when you start having a lot of stuff in your scripts.

Please see list of keys:
https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm